# Problem: VSCode DefinitionProvider opens the same document every time in a new tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have implemented [DefinitionProvider](https://github.com/anzory/vscode-gppl-support/blob/master/src/providers/GpplProcedureDefinitionProvider.ts), but it opens the same document every time in a new tab when navigating by definition. Too many tabs after a certain period of time. Does anyone know how to override this behavior?
Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks suspicious to me is [this line in your code](https://github.com/anzory/vscode-gppl-support/blob/dd48518c93665982e0c44abbf01e19a0c003768b/src/util/textParser.ts#L45):

```
...
Uri.parse(doc.uri + '#' + item.name),
...
```

Maybe adding a fragment to the original document URI makes VS Code think that each definition has to be opened in a separate editor.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to `doc.uri` and everything was fine.
Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!